# Use a T-bar as a snowboarder without pain

Tags: equipment, injuries, snowboarding

***Disclaimer:*** I originally posted this question on [Lifehacks](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/4003/use-a-t-bar-as-a-snowboarder-without-pain), but it unfortunately belongs on here. Since both sites are in beta I will leave the original question online.

I'd describe myself as a rather experienced snowboarder respectively T-bar rider. I used to fall out the T-bar when I was a beginner. So now, riding the T-bar to the top isn't a problem at all. I'm having a problem with the pain I get in my inner thigh. If it's one T-bar a day it's not bad at all. But if 90% of lifts are T-bars and I'm riding a whole week in the same resort, the pain in the evenings is tremendous.

I used to ride ski before riding snowboard, and as a skier the T-bars aren't a problem. They just pull at your butt and it won't hurt - even after a week.

I thought about placing a small cushion at my inner thigh but I'm worried, that it will restrict me while riding down the hills.
Pulling with my arms only temporarily decreases the pressure on my thigh.
I hope there's a hacky solution to prevent the pain in my inner thigh which hopefully won't restrict my leg in movement while riding my snowboard.

Possible solution could be using some kind of **climbing harness** as [suggested by MaxD](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/4003/use-a-t-bar-as-a-snowboarder-without-pain#comment5995_4003), but I haven't tried that.

Comment: Are you placing the bar behind your front leg or back leg? Also is your back leg strapped in or free?

Comment: @diggers3 Behind my front leg. My back leg is **not** strapped in.

Comment: what you can try is repositioning of your rear foot. Putting it next to your front foot can have some effect, but you will have less balance. The other thing you can do is holding the bar with your front hand and put other hand on the other side of the bar(if you're alone). Then you can pull yourself forward a bit with your front arm and use other hand to reposition the bar a bit, so that it hurts less

Comment: @Novarg I have tried both of your suggestions. When the track gets steeper I automatically place my rear foot close to the front foot (behind it, since next to it isn't possible because of the angle of the binding) to reduce the pressure. Pulling with my hands only works to reposition the T-bar before there's a steep section or to reduce the pain temporarily. Short rides are ok, bearable. I only have problems with **10mins lifts** with **>50% gradient**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would consider putting the bar behind your back leg, essentially under your butt cheek.

Here is a short video:

[ehow.com Riding a T-Bar on a Snowboard](http://www.ehow.com/video_4459050_do-t_bar-snowboarding.html)

Comment: I couldn't try this the whole week, but the last day. It definitely doesn't hurt. But I think the T-Bar doesn't hold as good as placing it between my legs (e.g. riding hands free, for drinking or eating) plus my back leg got numb, if the ride goes on long/is steep. 
I tried placing the T-Bar **on** and **under** my butt cheek - same effect.

Comment: I was able to test this thoroughly the last few days and it seems to be the easiest and best solution. I had to get used to it at first, also because my back leg is getting pulled to the front and I'm therefore not standing completely sideways anymore. Anyways, with some training I was even able to drink and eat while riding the T-Bar. I just had to be more aware of the bumps ahead. It is a quite unpleasant feeling at the butt of my back leg after some days but by far not as bad as the aching inner thigh after a week of riding the T-Bar the "usual" way.

Answer (score 2):

I experienced the same problem, I would just take my scarf, wrap it once around it, so when I sit on it I won't lose it but I could take it away easily, and then use the rest as u cushion.

It's not the best solution, but it was the easiest for me and it took away alot of the pressure on my leg

Answer (score 1):

I tend to hook it behind my front leg, but I do rest against the upright/cable with my arm/hand. This gives you more freedom to move the point of pressure, especially on a long/steep climb, and as I have damage to my spine from an old injury I need some way to do this, but it does preclude eating/drinking.

As I don't eat or drink while on the board this doesn't bother me, but it might annoy you if that is what you like to do.